# create a chart with date values in highchart

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highcharts to display a chart with number of player per hour.

I'm getting the data using ajax and this this is the result when I log the data :

```
 [[1450656000, 73309], [1450659600, 70889], [1450663200, 66651], [1450666800, 60078], [1450670400, 52893], [1450674000, 46222],....
```

as you can notice all the Unix timestamps are hours

```
1450656000 : Mon, 21 Dec 2015 00:00:00 GMT
1450659600 : Mon, 21 Dec 2015 02:00:00 GMT
1450663200 : Mon, 21 Dec 2015 03:00:00 GMT
1450666800 : Mon, 21 Dec 2015 04:00:00 GMT
1450670400 : Mon, 21 Dec 2015 05:00:00 GMT
```

but when I use this data to populate the chart I'm getting something like this :

For the first date which is `1450656000` I'm getting this date instead :

[image]

For the third date which is `1450663200` I'm getting this date instead :

[image]

and the same for the rest.

So why I'm not getting dates right in the chart ?

Comment: These are in seconds. Highcharts needs `datetime` values in milliseconds. Multiply by 1000.

Comment: @HalvorStrand thats worked thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript you should use timestamps in miliseconds, instead of UNIX (seconds). To convert between formats, multiply your timestamps by 1000.